# Facebook Comments - Loading Graphic While Waiting

Tags: facebook-comments

I'm using the Facebook Comments plugin for a local travel website in an area with poor internet. When the net is slow often the comments plugin takes forever or does not load at all. When it doesn't load it is just blank space instead which makes the page look odd. I want users to know that there should be content there.

Any ideas for how I could display a LOADING graphic while waiting for the Facebook Comments plugin to load? And then maybe if it hasn't after 10 or 15 seconds it returns an error message in that space instead.

I think a possibility might lie in the #Comments value that Facebook returns. Maybe a graphic could be loaded until that value is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution elsewhere - maybe it will help someone else with a similar problem:

Just replace this snippet with the current one you have where you want the count to appear,

Place the gif image in the same folder as the html file. Or change the path in the src="" to the correct path on your server.
You should see a loading animation while the count of comments from facebook updates.

Comment: Just replace this snippet with the current one you have where you want the count to appear,  
<fb:comments-count href=http://www.yoursite.com/><img src="indicator.gif"/></fb:comments-count>
Place the gif image in the same folder as the html file. Or change the path in the src="" to the correct path on your server.
You should see a loading animation while the count of comments from facebook updates.